# How to change a scroll bar height?

Tags: javascript, scroll, tailwind-css

**This is my tailwind scroll bar and I want to change its height how can I do that? The below image shows its height. I cannot change the `sm:h-96` can you suggest to me an method to change the height ?**

[image]

```
 {/** Chat Scroll View */}
  <div class=" text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg border w-full max-w-xl sm:h-96 p-4 overflow-y-scroll scrollbar border-solid border-2 border-red-500">
    <div class="space-y-1">
      <div className="entry cursor-pointer transform hover:scale-105 duration-300 transition-transform bg-white mb-4 rounded p-4 flex shadow-md">
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/300"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-green-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">Ryann Remo</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">15 April</small>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-xs bg-red-500 text-white rounded-full h-6 w-6 leading-6 text-center inline-block">
              23
            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="entry cursor-pointer transform hover:scale-105 duration-300 transition-transform bg-white mb-4 rounded p-4 flex shadow-md">
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/300"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-green-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">Ryann Remo</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">15 April</small>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-xs bg-red-500 text-white rounded-full h-6 w-6 leading-6 text-center inline-block">
              23
            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="entry cursor-pointer transform hover:scale-105 duration-300 transition-transform bg-white mb-4 rounded p-4 flex shadow-md">
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/500"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">Karp Bonolo</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">15 April</small>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-xs bg-red-500 text-white rounded-full h-6 w-6 leading-6 text-center inline-block">
              10
            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="entry cursor-pointer transform hover:scale-105 duration-300 transition-transform bg-white mb-4 rounded p-4 flex shadow-md">
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/500"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">Karp Bonolo</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">15 April</small>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-xs bg-red-500 text-white rounded-full h-6 w-6 leading-6 text-center inline-block">
              10
            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="entry cursor-pointer transform hover:scale-105 duration-300 transition-transform bg-white mb-4 rounded p-4 flex shadow-md border-l-4 border-red-500">
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/200"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">Mercedes Yemelyan</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">15 April</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="entry cursor-pointer transform hover:scale-105 duration-300 transition-transform bg-white mb-4 rounded p-4 flex shadow-md">
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/600"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">Cadi Kajetán</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">15 April</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="entry cursor-pointer transform hover:scale-105 duration-300 transition-transform bg-white mb-4 rounded p-4 flex shadow-md">
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/650"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">Rina Samuel</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">15 April</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {/** Chat Scroll View */}
```

Comment: There is no concept of scroll bar height in React - React is not aware of these things. You'll need to change these things with CSS and HTML, as you would without React. Removing "React" from tags and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the height based on your preference you can use an `arbitrary value` like `h-[120px]` or `h-[30rem]` or `h-[180px]` for example. you can change the value inside the square brackets according to the height you want.

You can learn more about arbitrary values ​​in the tailwind documentation here:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values